# Looking for a tv series with a food processor that gave out everyone's favourite food

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw a science fiction TV show from the late 1990s or early 2000s, on a sci-fi TV station.

It featured a food processor on an alien planet, that gave out the food that every user desired. The food the machine gave out was the same orange looking fruit slice. But when different people ate the alien food, it tasted like what they were craving for. A food that can taste like your desire.

Answer (score 14):

## I think you're thinking of an episode of *Sliders* called "[The Last of Eden](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0702786/)"

The episode is season 3, episode 20 of the series; aired March 28, 1997, so the time frame ought to fit. It wasn't an alien planet, but of course an alternate earth, alien to the main characters and having been "engineered" by an advanced culture. This would make the Earth of this episode a bit more "alien" than the more minor alterations of some earlier seasons, where many of the Earths they go to had reversed gender norms, or had never discovered penicillin.

From an episode guide at [brillig.com](http://www.brillig.com/sliders/episodes/43.html):

> The "Gineers" (Engineers) of this world tried to build a paradise for themselves and they came close in many ways--they invented a healing salve which can heal most ills and **fruit which can taste like anything you want, from steak to a cheeseburger**.

The "fruit" was given to the sliders by another character so as far as I can tell you never see where it comes from, but there is a scene involving the characters marveling at how it tastes like whatever they want (as mentioned in the quote above, steak and cheeseburger are given as examples). I tried to find a good photo of the fruit, but this is the best I could find from an episode review on [earthprime.com](https://earthprime.com/reviews/the-last-of-eden-review/):

[image: Professor Arturo eating the fruit.]

I recall this scene, and I'm pretty sure the <strike>prop was just an orange slice</strike>.

### EDIT

Okay, I've rewatched the episode, and have some dialog for the scene in question (I've bolded the distinct tastes mentioned):

> Remmy: It's good. Tastes like **apples**.
>
> Arturo: Hmm... I really fancy a piece of **steak**, myself. [Arturo takes a bite.] It is steak! [Takes another.] This is extraordinary. Anything that you can think of, it tastes like. Try it.
>
> Remmy: **Cheeseburger**. [Remmy takes a bite. Laughs.] It does. How do they do that?
>
> Arturo: I don't know. They must have been remarkable engineers.

Also, here is a better photo of the fruit, which seems to be more like a prickly pear or [kiwano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumis_metuliferus).

[image: Remmy with the fruit.]

Comment: I immediately thought of this episode as well. Very good chance it matches OPs question.

Comment: *"can taste like anything you want, from steak to a cheeseburger"* << So basically it always tastes like beef? ;-)

Comment: @Stef It's mentioned that it tastes like apples as well, although that was before they realize its variable properties.